# Ubuntu hang on boot due to unknown error

Tags: drivers, kernel

```
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel:  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: renamed from eth0
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0813, bcdDevice=90.11
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1: Product: USB3.0 Hub
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hub 2-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=1392, bcdDevice= 2.00
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-3: Product: Apple Watch Magnetic Charging Cable
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-3: SerialNumber: FTL10970F2JLNWLAU
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0b00, idProduct=5483, bcdDevice= 0.04
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2: Product: 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hub 1-1.2:1.0: USB hub found
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hub 1-1.2:1.0: 5 ports detected
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-9: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608, bcdDevice=60.90
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-9: Product: USB2.0 Hub
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hub 1-9:1.0: USB hub found
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hub 1-9:1.0: 4 ports detected
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usbhid: USB HID core driver
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hid-generic 0003:05AC:1392.0001: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Apple Inc. Apple Watch Magnetic Charging Ca>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0b00, idProduct=0483, bcdDevice= 0.04
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2: Product: 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hub 2-1.2:1.0: USB hub found
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hub 2-1.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=5483, bcdDevice= 0.04
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: Product: 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.1: Manufacturer: Generic
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hub 1-1.2.1:1.0: USB hub found
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hub 1-1.2.1:1.0: 5 ports detected
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.3: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c548, bcdDevice= 5.01
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.3: Product: USB Receiver
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.3: Manufacturer: Logitech
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.3/1-1.2.3:1.0/0003:046D:C548.>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:C548.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0->
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: input: Logitech USB Receiver Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.3/1-1.2.3:1.1/0003:046D>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: input: Logitech USB Receiver Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.3/1-1.2.3:1.>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0483, bcdDevice= 0.04
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2.1: Product: 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2.1: Manufacturer: Generic
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hub 2-1.2.1:1.0: USB hub found
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hub 2-1.2.1:1.0: 4 ports detected
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: input: Logitech USB Receiver System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.3/1-1.2.3:1.1/>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:C548.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.2>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:C548.0004: hiddev1,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0->
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.4: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b, bcdDevice=12.11
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.4: Product: USB Receiver
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.4: Manufacturer: Logitech
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.4:1.0/0003:046D:C52B.>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:C52B.0005: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0->
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: input: Logitech USB Receiver Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.4:1.1/0003:046D>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: input: Logitech USB Receiver Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.4:1.>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2.1.2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153, bcdDevice=33.00
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2.1.2: Product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2.1.2: Manufacturer: Realtek
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 2-1.2.1.2: SerialNumber: 0033000001
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: fbcon: Taking over console
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usbcore: registered new device driver r8152-cfgselector
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: input: Logitech USB Receiver System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.4:1.1/>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:C52B.0006: input,hiddev2,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:C52B.0007: hiddev3,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0->
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: r8152-cfgselector 2-1.2.1.2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.5: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=1100, bcdDevice= 1.01
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.5: Product: USB2.0 HID
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: usb 1-1.2.5: Manufacturer: Realtek
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hid-generic 0003:0BDA:1100.0008: hiddev4,hidraw7: USB HID v1.11 Device [Realtek USB2.0 HID] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.2>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0007: hiddev2,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: input: Logitech Wireless Device PID:406b Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: input: Logitech Wireless Device PID:406b Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.4:1>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:406B.0009: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Device PID:406b] on usb-0>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: input: Logitech M585/M590 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.4:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.000>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406B.0009: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech M585/M590] on usb-0000:0>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: r8152 2-1.2.1.2:1.0: PHY patch request fail
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: r8152 2-1.2.1.2:1.0: load rtl8156b-2 v2 04/27/23 successfully
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: WARNING: CPU: 8 PID: 102 at drivers/net/usb/r8152.c:7665 r8156b_hw_phy_cfg+0x1421/0x1430 [r8152]
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: Modules linked in: hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj r8152(+) mii hid_generic usbhid hid nvme r8169 crc32_pclmul n>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: CPU: 8 PID: 102 Comm: kworker/8:1 Not tainted 6.5.0-14-generic #14-Ubuntu
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. H610M H DDR4/H610M H DDR4, BIOS FF 08/09/2022
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: Workqueue: events_long rtl_hw_phy_work_func_t [r8152]
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: RIP: 0010:r8156b_hw_phy_cfg+0x1421/0x1430 [r8152]
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: Code: be 00 a4 00 00 48 89 df 81 e2 ff f7 00 00 e8 16 5d ff ff e9 96 ec ff ff be 01 00 00 00 48 89 df e8 44 73 ff f>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: RSP: 0000:ffffa859804d7df8 EFLAGS: 00010293
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: RAX: 0000000000000001 RBX: ffff9803c10bf9c0 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: RBP: ffffa859804d7e18 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff9803c10bf9c0
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: R13: ffff9803c10bfda8 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff9803c1397180
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff980b5fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: CR2: 00007ffd4496fbf8 CR3: 00000006e503a000 CR4: 0000000000750ee0
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: PKRU: 55555554
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: Call Trace:
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel:  <TASK>
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel:  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel:  ? __warn+0x89/0x160
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel:  ? r8156b_hw_phy_cfg+0x1421/0x1430 [r8152]
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel:  ? report_bug+0x17e/0x1b0
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel:  ? handle_bug+0x51/0xa0
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel:  ? exc_invalid_op+0x18/0x80
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel:  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel:  ? r8156b_hw_phy_cfg+0x1421/0x1430 [r8152]
```

Attached is my boot log. In this section, there's an error

```
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: r8152 2-1.2.1.2:1.0: PHY patch request fail
Jan 14 11:02:25 hh-CF kernel: r8152 2-1.2.1.2:1.0: load rtl8156b-2 v2 04/27/23 successfully
```

that prevents me from booting for a few minutes. Does anybody know what this problem is related to? I'm pretty stumped on what it even relates to. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Hi, sounds like the error is related to the `Realtek USB Ethernet adapter (rtl8156b-2) ` have you tried to unplug it or disable it(in BIOS) and reboot the system again?

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried rebooting it a few times and the system has gone away though now my Ethernet adapter doesn't work.

It turns out that this was not my motherboard's adapter but an ethernet port in my display which I did not know existed. However, the display ethernet port now doesn't work any more. It seems like a problem with the BIOS registering which ethernet port to use as when I tried using my screen's ethernet port, the one on my motherboard doesn't work anymore.